# Destroying lists with ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I had two separate generic views:

```
 class DetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
      ...

 сlass ListView(generics.ListAPIView):

     def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.query_params.get('q', None)
        if query == 'registered':
             ...
```

The first one just performs generic operations on a model object. The second gives a list filtered using a `q` GET param.

To be able to delete filtered objects I added `delete` method to the `ListView`:

```
 class ListView(generics.ListAPIView):
      ...
      def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           self.get_queryset().delete()
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

What I want is to combine this into a `ViewSet`. Unfortunately I do not see a proper way of accomplishing that. `DefaultRouter` creates a list method without a `DELETE` method allowed. And `delete()` method added by a `ModelViewSet` seems to be called only for a deletion with pk specified. So it seems there is no way of writing one `delete()` for a specific method and another for a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to plug the delete action to the list entry point, you'll need to override the routers and redefine the routes to include delete for lists. You browse the [source code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L90) for an example of the default routes.

Comment: I was thinking about that. I did not like it because I have to write all the router myself. I do not see how to just add a `delete` method for a only a list.

Comment: You don't have to write the router yourself, simple alter the routes to map the list/delete to -say- batch_delete

Comment: Could you give an example of altering exactly the list route? Because routes are specified as a class variable. And the only way I see is to subclass DefaultRoute and redefine it.